# which file opencart framework calls to read the url and render the matched page

Tags: opencart

As I have checked it's first go to index.php and after that how it load a particular controller I did not get it. I have also checked the `url_alias` table. But still did not get it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start with index.php

Code :- // Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

In above action class collect the route information

Action class check whatever you are requesting for eg. product controller this exist or not if it does not exist then it will initialize index method to its properties but if controller is exist then then it will initilize respective method to its own property

next this action object is pass to dispatch() function next to it
// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

dispatch contain by system/engine/front.php class
in this execute() function is responsible to call method of requested controller 

till now request is reach towards controller(of respective requested controller name for eg. product/category.php)

in controller file last method in index method last method call is render() which is there in all the conroller file this method is responsible to render the view of respective controller.

This method defination is there in system/engine/controller.php file in the you will get require_once(specific view as per the request at initial level)
require(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->template);

    enter code here

i think this will help you
```